# last insert id with zend db table abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework, insert, zend-db

variable `$tablemodel` in an instance of a model which extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, if i do

```
$tablemodel->insert($data)
```

to insert data. Is there any method or property to get last insert id?

regards

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try

```
$id = $tablemodel->insert($data);  
echo $id;
```

Comment: In my version of Zend `insert` returns an int, but it's the number of affected rows not the last inserted row!

Comment: Zend 2 does not return the id, it returns the affected amount of rows.

Answer (score 32):

```
$last_id = $tablemodel->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use lastInsertId Method

```
echo 'last inserted id: ' . $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Where does `$db` come from?

Answer (score 2):

use after insert query

```
$this->dbAdapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();
```

Comment: Now **THIS** one works for a change. I use an auto incremented primary key 'id'. So if you have your adapter, get the driver and it should work. Also Zend-Db v2.9

Answer (score 1):

`$insert_id = $this->db->getLastId()` worked for me