# zend framework insert() and LAST_INSERT_ID() screw up

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework

so I tried to use Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql's insert() method....

and then after that I issued the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` command....

but then for some reason, that command always return 0 rather than the actual inserted ID...

when I tried to use normal INSERT query, and then get the last insert id, it works just fine so I guess it's some zend framework screw up...

does anybody know how to get around this?

the insert() method only returns 1 if it succeeds rather than the id, so the solution for this: [last insert id with zend db table abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842064/last-insert-id-with-zend-db-table-abstract)  doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zend_Db_Adaptor](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) Documentation explains

> Some RDBMS brands support auto-incrementing primary keys. A table defined this way generates a primary key value automatically during an INSERT of a new row. The return value of the insert() method is not the last inserted ID, because the table might not have an auto-incremented column. Instead, the return value is the number of rows affected (usually 1).
>
> If your table is defined with an
>   auto-incrementing primary key, you can
>   call the lastInsertId() method after
>   the insert. This method returns the
>   last value generated in the scope of
>   the current database connection.

So ...

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Should work

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear. Nevertheless, I think that at least a part of a problem you have is that you are confusing insert method from `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` (or `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`) with the one from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`. Both these classes have methods that are called `insert`, but they work differently.

`insert` methods from `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` returns the **"The number of affected rows"**, while `insert` from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` returns **"The primary key of the row inserted"**.

The link that you provided is using insert from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`. However,  it seems that you are using insert from `` `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract ``. For this reason you are always getting 1 in return.

Answer (score 0):

In ZF2 you could use :

```
$id = $this->lastInsertValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In ZF3 & Zend Expressive, this is the only way to do it:

```
$this->dbAdapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();
```